# Stuck on rearranging of this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to get from

$[(1-p)f+p(1-f)](1+v)-[(1-p)(1-f)+pf] = x$

to $(2+v)(f+p-2pf)-1 = x$

but I'm stuck. I'd appreciate any tips on what I should I do after the following.

$(f+p-2pf)(1+v) + (f + p - 2pf) - 1 = x$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have gone from the first to the third, then you can just pull out the common factor of $(f+p-2pf)$ to get the the second equation.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

As Calvin mentioned, you have already done the hard work and have:

$(f+p-2pf)(1+v) + (f + p - 2pf) - 1 = x$

So, we just factor out the common term and have:

$(f+p-2pf)\left[(1+v) + 1\right] - 1 = x$, so:

$$(2+v)(f+p-2pf)- 1 = x$$

Comment: Complete hint, Amzoti. Have a wonderful day ahead. ++

Comment: Nice work here! (It's always nice when the OP has done most of the work, and you can help them realize that they're *virtually there.*